# Hot sort by different meta keys in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have a rental custom post type.
The rentals have prices, the price is stored in the rental table. 
The rentals also have a meta key "featured". It has a value of "on" or "off".
So far, I could manage to sort the rentals by feature and then by price. So the featured items come first, and then the others and the item are sorted by price.
This is nice, but my customer came up with another idea.
The featured rentals pay a monthly price, and it is not fair to always show the ones with the lowest price on top.
So I should order the featured items by date, they would come first , and then the other items, but the other items would be ordered by price.

I think it could be done with a subquery, but I have no idea how.

This the query I run now:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, 
   FROM wp_posts 
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
   INNER JOIN wp_st_rental as tb ON wp_posts.ID = tb.post_id 
   WHERE 1=1 AND 
   ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships 
   WHERE      term_taxonomy_id IN (253) ) ) AND 
   ( wp_postmeta.meta_key =    'is_featured' ) AND 
   wp_posts.post_type = 'st_rental' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
   AND wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_st_location_relationships
   WHERE 1=1  AND post_type IN ('st_rental')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
   ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC, CAST(st_rental_price as DECIMAL) ASC 
   LIMIT 0, 350
```

Could you help me to modify this so that the featured come first, they are ordered by date, then the others and they are ordered by price.
Thank you!

Comment: It might be useful to see your actual query. Also, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I copied my actual query.

Comment: Nope. You didn't.